# Limit at (0,0) of $\frac{xy^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2 +y^4}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\text{Let}\ f(x,y) = \frac{xy^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2 +y^4}$$

WolframAlpha tells me that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f(x,y)$ does not exist. To prove the non-existence of the limit, I tried three different paths ($y=kx, y=kx^2, y=kx^3)$ and they all equal zero. From the graph of the function it looks like the limit is indeed zero. Also I thought I was able to prove the limit does indeed exist at $(0,0)$ with the epsilon-delta definition:
$$y^2 \leq x^2+y^2 \leq x^2 + y^4 \iff \frac{y^2}{x^2+y^4} \leq 1 \overset{|x|<1}{\iff} \frac{|x|y^2}{x^2+y^4} \leq 1 \iff \frac{|x|y^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2+y^4} \leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \iff \left|\frac{xy^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2+y^4} - 0\right|\leq \left|\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-0)^2}\right| \lt δ := ε $$

So for $δ = ε$ we have that $\|x -(0,0)\| < δ \implies |f(x,y) - 0| < ε$

I'm confused

Comment: $y^2\le y^4$ is false for small $y$, so your argument breaks. (I haven’t investigated the function myself though.)

Comment: Note also that wolframalpha says: "value may depend on x, y path in **complex space**". It sounds like the limit doens't exist with complex variables (I can't tell right now if that's plausible). I don't know how to make wolframalpha calculate the limit in the reals though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4} \le \dfrac{1}{2}$. This is true by the AM-GM inequality. Note that the inequality you claimed is wrong because the line $y^2 \le y^4$ is not true !

Comment: So the limit is indeed zero then, although my proof was wrong. I wonder why WolframAlpha gives me this answer then.

Answer (score 3):

One more possible way
$$\frac{xy^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2 +y^4}=\sqrt{ \frac{y^4x^4+y^6x^2}{(x^2 +y^4)^2}}\leqslant \sqrt{\frac{y^4x^4+y^6x^2}{2x^2y^4}}=\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{y^2}{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, by $y^2=v$ and polar coordinates, with $x=\rho\cos \theta$ and $v=\rho|\sin \theta|$, we obtain

$$ \frac{xy^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x^2 +y^4} =\frac{xv\sqrt{x^2+v}}{x^2 +v^2}=\sqrt \rho \cos \theta |\sin \theta| \sqrt{\rho\cos^2 \theta|\sin \theta|}\to 0$$